# PJSIP Library Build Error for Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, pjsip

Please help me. I try to build PJSIP library in Windows for Android by using Cygwin terminal. I follow steps exactly, but when I write `$ ./configre-android I get this error` - >

```
$ ./configure-android
./configure-android: line 3: $'\r': command not found
./configure-android: line 5: $'\r': command not found
./configure-android: line 71: syntax error near unexpected token `$'do\r''
'/configure-android: line 71: `  for i in `$NDK_OUT`; do
```

I used this steps to build sources are

> Download sources from PJSIP site. Pay attention if you will compile
>   on Windows machine download .zip file, if on Unix machine (including
>   OS X) then download .bz2 file.
>
> Go to pjlib/include/pj/ from the downloaded sources. Create (or
>   overwrite) a file called config_site.h. Copy the following code
>   snippet
>
> `#define PJ_CONFIG_ANDROID 1`
>      `#include <pj/config_site_sample.h>`
>
> Open Cmd or Terminal
>
> Go to pjsip root folder (the downloaded sources)
>
> `$ cd /path/to/your/pjsip/dir`
>
> Export bash var ANDROID_NDK_ROOT as a environment variable.
>   Variable value should be the path of android ndk directory.
>
> `$ export ANDROID_NDK_ROOT=/path_to_android_ndk_dir`
>
> Perform build for target armeabi
>
> `$ ./configure-android`
>
> If you need to perform build for target `arm64-v8a` do $
>   `TARGET_ABI=armeabi-v8a ./configure-android --use-ndk-cflags`
>
> target `armeabi-v7a` do $ 
>      `TARGET_ABI=armeabi-v7a ./configure-android --use-ndk-cflags`
>
> target `x86` do `$ TARGET_ABI=x86 ./configure-android --use-ndk-cflags`
>
> Compile sources
>
> `$ make dep && make clean && make`

Comment: are you sure you have downloaded the .zip file and not the .bz2 one ?

Comment: If not, open script file using Notepad++, go to Menu -> Edit -> EOL Conversion -> Unix/OSX Format. Then try to run it again

Comment: @HesnliEldar did u fix ur problem if yes can you help me out?

Answer (score 0):

This fixed problem for me:

`tr -d '\015' < configure-android > configure-android2`

After this launch `configure-android2`, not `configure-android`